# How to get attributes of the form elements?

Tags: forms

I know that it should be easy, but currently it doesnt work.
In my function I want to get #title of each element in the form. My form is fieldset "add_company". For example, when I try to get #title:

```
$msg = '';
foreach ($form['values']['add_company'] as $item)
    $msg .= $item['#title'] . ' ';
```

But I receive nothing.

Second part of question is when i try smth like this:

```
$value = $form_state['values']['add_company']['offers']['#title'];
```

I receive "O", but not "Offers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
function my_form_validate(OR_SUBMIT)($form, &$form_state)
{
  $msg = '';
  foreach(element_children($form[FIELDSET_NAME]) as $key => $value) {
    $msg .= $form[FIELDSET_NAME][$value]['#title'] . ' ';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx, I've checked your solution and it's almost right answer. Not [$key], but [$value]. Please, correct it so I can mark it as right answer.

Comment: @ZiCold Hi, thanks for the clarification, I edited my answer.

Comment: Well, I've marked it as right answer. Thank you for the answer!